# Hot question generally have high views as well as high votes?

Tags: discussion, voting, hot-questions

Recently having few observation stack exchange site , I noticed that hot question is high voted.
When question is said to be hot question all the user sees it first or user sees that question before any other and if question is good and worthy to be a hot question it is high voted and views are too high.
Is it so? 
So if ask a question  and I get too many votes in less time does my question becomes a hot question  in that site ?